# Android fragment simple backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack, fragmentmanager

I have one activity containing one container that will receive 2 fragments.
Once the activity initialises i start the first fragment with:

```
showFragment(new FragmentA());

private void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getTag())
            .addToBackStack(fragment.getTag())
            .commit();
}
```

Then when the user clicks on FragmentA, I receive this click on Activity level and I call:

```
showFragment(new FragmentB());
```

Now when I press back button it returns to fragment A (thats correct) and when i press again back button it show empty screen (but stays in the same activity). I would like it to just close the app (since the activity has no parent).

There are a lot of posts related with Fragments and backstack, but i can't find a simple solution for this. I would like to avoid the case where I have to check if im doing back press on Fragment A or Fragment B, since i might extend the number of Fragments and I will need to maintain that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting blank screen because when you add first fragment you are `calling addToBackStack()` due to which you are adding a blank screen unknowingly!

now what you can do is call the following method in `onBackPressed()` and your problem will be solved

```
  public void moveBack()
    {
//FM=fragment manager
        if (FM != null && FM.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1)
         {
           FM.popBackStack();
         }else {
           finish();
         }
    }
```

**DO NOT CALL SUPER IN ONBACKPRESSED();**

just call the above method!

Comment: my problem was that i didn't realize that i was adding a blank screen to back stack without knowing :/ Then checking if FM.getBackStackEntryCount()>1 solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Fragment concept is very tricky and vast!! anyways glad could help!

Answer (score 0):

addToBackStack(fragment.getTag())

use it for fragment B only, not for fragment A

Answer (score 0):

I think your fragment A is not popped out correctly, try to use add fragment rather replace to have proper back navigation, however You can check count of back stack using:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
```

and you can also directly call `finish()` in activity `onBackPressed()` when you want your activity to close on certain fragment count.